# LWJGL Game not properly ending

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I currently have a simple problem with LWJGL right now. If I were to run my game, it does actually run everything correctly and it appears to close out correctly, but when I look inside my Task Manager, I notice that my game is taking up 25% CPU after I close it (about 2-3% when it's actually running) and I'm thinking that I may have missed something when ending the application.

My main function code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        init();
    }catch(LWJGLException e){
        System.out.println("LWJGLException\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        gameLoop();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        cleanup();
    }
}
```

cleanup:

```
public static void cleanup(){
    System.out.println("Running cleanup code.");
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

It does actually manage to read "Running cleanup code." My problem is that I don't know if there is something else I need to do to clear out all of the processes. This game is also using a single thread.

Comment: I highly suggest that you avoid using `System.exit()` with all your might. This will mess up the graceful termination of your app. Perhaps you disallow LWJGL to properly close up all its resources when you force termination via `System.exit()` instead of normal termination. For example, even if you are only using a single thread of code yourself, who says that LWJGL is not using multi-threads in the background and need to be automatically cleaned up by the JVM (and not explicitly by your code) before termination? Try it out.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but there still seems to be a problem. I'm assuming that there is something with LWJGL or OpenGL that needs to be explicitly ended that I don't know of.

Comment: Sorry to hear it still didn't solve the problem. However, I stand by my belief that using `System.exit()` in a Java application is generally a bad idea. Good luck.

Comment: On the other hand, `System.exit()` is the only way to make sure that no non-daemon thread stops your application from exiting.

Comment: I have removed System.exit() from the code. I'll still try to search for my issue at some point. Apparently it won't be that big of an issue, because I'm the only one who gets it. If I give my game build to anyone else, their task manager shows it being removed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code at all, I think. If your problem is what I think it is you wouldn't be able to immediately fix it.

Here are some basic questions you should ask your self. What OS are you using? What is your Java version and/or LWJGL version? (Updating them might help) Have you ever heard of/or played a game called Minecraft? If you are using Linux and seen this when closing Minecraft then that could be the problem you're having.

Comment: I'm running Windows. Minecraft also doesn't seem to be giving my this issue. Since I'm the only one who seems to have it, I won't have to worry about it as much. I do think that it could be my java installation though. My java is all funky. I'll have to take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem on 64-bit windows. App haven't closed when Runtime Exception (or any other uncaught exception) occured. Probably reason was throwing an exception in an independent thread which effected in closing display window, but all other threads were still working. I came up with brute force solution: overriding Thread method.

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
         @Override
         public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
         }});

    new LwjglApplication(new StartScreen(application), cfg);
```